# Why do I get a NullPointerException while autowiring an interface that extends MongoRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to write an access layer class that gets data from **MongoDB** using **Spring Data**, but I have the following problem:
I have the following interface:

```
public interface BlogDataRepository extends MongoRepository<Article, String> {
    public Article findArticleByName(String name);
}
```

and the access layer class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class BlogDataAccessLayer {

    @Autowired
    private BlogDataRepository dataRepository;
    ...
}
```

And finally a main class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Test implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        BlogDataAccessLayer layer = new BlogDataAccessLayer();

        Article article = new Article("test", "first article");
        layer.addArticle(article);
    }
}
```

Each time I'm trying to run the app I get a `NullPointerExeption` from `dataRepository` located in `BlogDataAccessLayer`.

I don't understand why `dataRepository` is not autowired. If I move `dataRepository` in `Test` it works.

Can somebody explain why I get this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll review your code from top to bottom,first thing to consider is using [`@Repository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) annotation in your data access layer, in this case `BlogDataRepository` interface should be annotated with this stereotype annotation.

In the sense of Domain Driven Design we should access repository layer through the service layer. so in your case `BlogDataAccessLayer` is act as Service layer and in this case `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is redundant and in Spring echo system service layer beans should annotated with [`@Service`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) annotation.

Last and most important part of your code, spring boot `@EnableAutoConfiguration` doesn't scan for beans in your class path and you should add [`@ComponentScan`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) to your main class, in your case `Test` class.

notice that in Spring Boot it's a good practice to place your main class in root package and other classes in their specific package. for example it's a good practice:

```
org->Application.java //Test
org.service->FooService.java // BlogDataAccessLayer
org.repository->FooRepository // BlogDataRepository
```

if you want to use beans into your client classes you should inject them. so in your case instantiating `BlogDataAccessLayer` with `new` keyword should be replaced with spring [`@Autowired`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) annotation. and also your `Test` class should has [`@Configuration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) annotation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to autowire `BlogDataAccessLayer` instead of instantiating. Then only the `BlogDataRepository` within that class gets autowired.